# Компиляция приложения, .pdb файл

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Все привет. Можно заметить, что после компиляции приложения **Visual Studio** помимо `.exe` файлов, `.dll` и прочих, добавляет еще и `.pdb` файлы.

Насколько мне известно, данные файлы позволяют увидеть чуть больше в информации об исключении. Если я не ошибаюсь, они позволяют увидеть в `StackTrace` файл и строку кода, в которой произошло исключение.

Вопрос, собственно есть ли еще какая то практическая польза от данных файлов (`.pdb`) в скомпилированном приложении?

Answer (score 7):

Наличие [файлов символов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B) (`.pdb`) на клиентской машине может быть полезно тем, что в случае возникновения необработанного исключения при наличии `.pdb` файла можно получить более детальный `stack trace`.

Например, создадим простое консольное приложение которое кидает исключение и посмотрим как оно будет выглядеть с файлом символов и без.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Do1();
        }

        static void Do1()
        {
            Do2();
        }

        static void Do2()
        {
            Do3();
        }

        static void Do3()
        {
            var i = 1;
            var s = "a";
            var b = true;
            throw new Exception("Any exception");
        }
    }
}
```

Запускаем без файла `.pdb` и получаем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запускаем с `.pdb` файлом и получаем:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно, во втором случае, в `stack trace` видны название файла и номер строки в которой произошло исключение.

Answer (score 2):

В pdb-файлах размещается отладочная информация.

Дело в том, что при компиляции информация о том, какой строке исходного кода соответствует та или иная конструкция в скомпилированном коде, отсутствует, она просто не нужна для выполнения. Точно так же информация о том, как называются локальные переменные, не включена в скомпилированный код.

Всю такую информацию, нужную для отладки, компилятор и складывает в pdb.

Остальная информация, наподобие того, где в стеке найти параметр или локальную переменную, или там определения классов/структур, в pdb для .NET не нужны, это и так есть в метаданных.

Дополнительное чтение по теме: [*PDB Files: What Every Developer Must Know*](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jrobbins/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know).

Comment: VladD, это понятно. Я предпочитаю удалять данные файлы из скомпилированного приложения, но я так же видел, что люди часто оставляют их,  аргументируя тем, что в случае исключения они  будут знать чуточку больше о проблеме, чем я. Может, конечно я чего-то недопонимаю, но мне кажется что достаточно просмотреть всю сопутствующую информацию находящуюся в исключении, что бы разобраться в проблеме. Поэтому отсюда вытекает вопрос, собственно выигрываю ли в чем-нибудь те люди, кто оставляет данные файлы в скомпилированном приложении или нет в случае возникновения исключения?

Comment: @sp7: Это зависит от того, что вы собираетесь _делать_ при возникновении исключения. PDB нужны отладчику. То есть если вы собираетесь на этой же машине запустить отладчик (например, отладчик запускается автоматически при креше), то они вам помогут.

Comment: @sp7: Но если это клиентская машина, то там они по идее не нужны. Если вы придёте туда с отладчиком, вы можете указать ему альтернативное расположение для pdb (например, на вашем pdb-сервере). Или можете просто перед запуском отладчика положить pdb куда нужно. Единственная проблема — вы должны будете вручную сопоставить версию исполняемого файла и версию PDB, они обязаны совпадать.

Comment: @sp7: На текст исключения наличие pdb не влияет. Это легко проверить вручную. На него влияют только ключи компиляции.